# Не получается сохранить qr code по api на python requests

Tags: python, requests

Cтолкнулся с такой проблемой: нужно получать qr-code по api. Написал код по документации, данной на сайте (me-qr). Когда qr-code сгенерировался, мне нужно сохранить его в папке.
Я написал вот такой код, qr генерируется, его сохраняю, но когда пытаюсь открыть, пишет "Формат не поддерживается".

```
import requests

url = "https://me-qr.com/api/qr/create/"

payload = {
    "token": "Tут токен",
    "qrType": 1,
    "title": "QR Code",
    "service": "api",
    "format": "png",
    "qrOptions": {
        "size": 300,
        "pattern": "square",
        "patternColor": "#000000",
        "patternBackground": "#ffffff",
        "cornetsInterior": "square",
        "cornetsInteriorColor": "#000000",
        "cornetsOuter": "square",
        "cornetsOuterColor": "#000000",
        "logotype": None,
        "logotypeSize": 0.3,
        "logotypeHideBackground": True,
        "logotypeMargin": 0
    },
    "qrFieldsData": {
        "link": "example.com"
    }
}

response = requests.post(url, json=payload, verify=False)

if response.status_code == 200:
    with open("qr_code.svg", "wb") as f:
        f.write(response.content)
    print("QR-код успешно сохранен в файле qr_code.png!")
else:
    print("Произошла ошибка при создании QR-кода.")
```

Так же я просто скопировал код с документации, но все равно та же ошибка(в конце я добавил сохранение)

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'https://me-qr.com/api/qr/create/' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "token": "тут токен",
  "qrType": 1,
  "title": "QR Code",
  "service": "api",
  "format": "png",
  "qrOptions": {
    "size": 300,
    "pattern": "square",
    "patternColor": "#000000",
    "patternBackground": "#ffffff",
    "cornetsInterior": "square",
    "cornetsInteriorColor": "#000000",
    "cornetsOuter": "square",
    "cornetsOuterColor": "#000000",
    "logotype": null,
    "logotypeSize": 0.3,
    "logotypeHideBackground": true,
    "logotypeMargin": 0
  },
  "qrFieldsData": {
    "link": "example.com"
  }
}' > output.png
```

Не могу понять как мне сохранять полученный куар код после его генерации. Помогите пожалуйста.

Вот что пишет после выполнения кода

```
InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host 'me-qr.com'. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#tls-warnings
  warnings.warn(
QR-код успешно сохранен в файле qr_code.png!
```

Comment: Лично у меня данный сайт вообще недоступен из России. Скорее всего у вас так же

Comment: Вас не смущает **with open("qr_code.svg", "wb") as f:**  .svg ?

Comment: а в curl вы записываете в .png

Comment: @Exord файл есть файл. Программе без разницы куда записывать данные. Расширение файла нужно только для того, чтобы другие программы могли распознавать "свои" файлы и предлагать пользователю их открыть.

Comment: Ага только товарищ пишет что при попытке открыть, "пишет "Формат не поддерживается". "

Comment: Да, верное замечание, не увидел

Comment: Программа может пытаться открыть svg файл, кишки которого записаны в png формате...

Comment: Я бы попробовал заглянуть глазами в записанный файл (через Far manager или ещё как) и посмотреть - есть там хоть похожесть на содержание PNG файлов, какая там сигнатура в начале и т.д. Что там вообще.

Comment: Если вы генерируете png (на что намекает `"format": "png"` в payload), то и сохранять нужно с расширением png. Т.е. при открытии должно быть не `open("qr_code.svg", "wb")` а например `open("qr_code.png", "wb")`

Comment: Действительно, я не увидел что у меня сохранялось в свг, но это не решило проблему. Все так же не поддерживается формат

Comment: Внутрь записанного файла глазами смотрели? Может там вообще текст об ошибке от веб-сервера вместо того, что ожидается.